# JButtons Only Working When Mouse Hovers Over

Tags: java, swing, hover, jbutton, mouse

I am a beginner in Java and programming overall, and I started by making a simple `JFrame` with a few buttons. Now when I created the buttons, the only way they would appear is if I hovered over them with my mouse.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame {

public Main() {
    setTitle("Test");
    setSize(600, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    JButton b = new JButton("Derp");
    p.add(b);
    add(b);
    setVisible(true);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
} 

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    new Main();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Under Construction...", 240, 250);

}

}
```

Help would be appreciated, also please note I do not know that much about Java and I don't know a descent amount of the languages. Also, a way to make the buttons have the Aero texture instead of the default one would be nice :)

Comment: Revalidate it outside of its constructor.

Comment: As advice to a newbie, I am going to recommend that you learn programming first, and maybe then learn GUI programming using just Swing components, and only after that do anything that involves `paint()` and `repaint()`.  It is quite possible (and quite common) to write GUI programs that have buttons, panels, layouts, text areas, JTables, JScrollPanes, colors, textures, and more complexity than you'll ever want to deal with without once having to call either of these methods.

Comment: `p.add(b); add(b);` any component can have only one parent, so that should be `p.add(b); add(p);`.  BTW - That panel will entirely cover the custom painting.

Comment: *"Also, a way to make the buttons have the Aero texture instead of the default one would be nice :)"*  SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk.  If you wish to improve the look of the buttons, that is best dealt with on a dedicated question thread.  Also, don't forget to ask a (clear, specific) question!  You forgot to add a question(1) on this one.. 1) As opposed to problem descriptions and requirements - neither of which are questions in themselves..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you override `paint` you need to call `super.paint(g);` as the first line.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g); // <-- add this.
    g.drawString("Under Construction...", 240, 250);
}
```

Also, you should move your logic off the `main()` thread; like

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new Main();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can we also discuss that this an horrendously bad idea (overriding `paint` of top level containers) and should be avoid for this and other various reasons...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Since you bring it up, but also it's not a great idea to call any methods that depend on an instance state from a constructor (since the instance isn't constructed yet).